# Is it possible to download raw accelerometer data from samsung active 2 watch and save as csv?

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, wearables

I am trying to save all raw accelerometer data from samsung active 2 and save it as a csv which I can post process. Has anyone tried this and have any luck?